# How can I convert a 2D image into sketch matrix like autocad image using JS

Tags: javascript, image, three.js, wireframe

I am working on some project basically for the real estate and kind of stuck in some feature where I need some help.

I have a 3D scene ready using three JS and rendered on screen, but sometimes the user wants to see in 2D and sometimes in wireframe.

see images below[image: color Image]
[image: sketch Image]
one way to do is to keep the camera at top of the 3D view and make model wireframe true.
but I am looking for the alternate way to convert a 2D image of top view into the structure like above. Is there any library or method that can help in solving this.

Thanks

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking for, do you want to convert an image of the plan into some sort of 3d-model?

Comment: if you see the first photo, you can see it is the 2D image of the 3D floor plan. and on some website I found this, when we see this 2D image without textures, it shows up as a wireframe mesh image.

Comment: Given that the tree model has a different shape in 2D than to does in 3D, I'd say each object has a different model for each mode. In 3D, it has color materials, responds to lights, etc. In 2D, it might be a set of lines, or even images layered using the 3D model positioning. If these objects come from a library of pre-defined shapes, it's easy to imagine that the 2D mode could even be rendered completely in HTML/CSS.